# Ordering bar chart in python by decreasing value

Tags: bar-chart, plotly

I've created a stacked bar chart using plotly and would like to order the categorical variables on the x-axis according to decreasing values, based on their corresponding total y value. What is the best way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: a little bit of your code and data would be useful. Should be easy to do, but not enough information here to help.

Answer (score 4):

Hard without seeing your code, so I'll presume you're using pandas with plotly.

If so, it would be:

```
df['Your_X_Series'].sort_values(ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

And then plot the series.